# Xml file contains no data after i run my application

Tags: java, spring-batch

[console after app runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G64hK.png)I'm building an application that reads data from h2 database and write it into xml file. The program runs with no errors, but there is no data been written to my xml file.

I created main class
controller class: (family.java) contains setters.
Test Config class: contains all steps needed to read and write the data.
application Properties: contains the information needed to connect to database.
family Data:  file i created to transfer data from h2db.
data Sql file : the sql file i use to create my table.

application.prperties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:navin
spring.datasource.data-username=sa
spring.datasource.data-password=
```

data.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS family;

CREATE TABLE family (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO family (name, description) VALUES
  ('zakaria', 'I am the father'),
  ('Yahya', 'I am the oldest son in the house'),
  ('Zaid', 'I am the middle son in the house'),
  ('Mouad', 'I am the cutest boy in the house');

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class TestConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("dataSorce.driverClassName");
        dataSource.setUrl("dataSource.url");
        dataSource.setUsername("dataSource.username");
        dataSource.setPassword("dataSource.password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    public JdbcCursorItemReader<family> reader(){
        JdbcCursorItemReader<family> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<family>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setSql("SELECT id,name,description FROM family");
        reader.setRowMapper(new FamilyRowMapper());

        return reader;

    }

    public class FamilyRowMapper implements RowMapper<family> {

        @Override
        public family mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            family user = new family();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            user.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

            return user;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemWriter<family> writer(){
        StaxEventItemWriter<family> writer = new StaxEventItemWriter<family>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("familyData.xml"));

        Map<String, String> aliasesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        aliasesMap.put("family", "Test_example.family");
        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAliases(aliasesMap);

        writer.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        writer.setRootTagName("familyData");
        writer.setOverwriteOutput(true);

        return writer;

    }
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<family, family> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportFamilyJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportFamilyJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(step1())
        .end()
        .build();   
    }

}

//family class
public class family {

    int id;
    String name;
    String description;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String saySomething () {
        return "my name is :" + name + " " + description + " " + id;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please also show us your application.properties and data.sql?

Comment: Is the file created (but still empty) or not created at all?

Comment: #Stefan: I already added what you ask for on my post. Thank you                            
#Mahmoud: The file is already created, but after i run the app it is still empty. Thank you

Comment: ok thanks. I see no 'COMMIT' instruction in your SQL script so probably data is not committed in the db (hence the reader reads nothing and the writer writes noting too). Are you sure your items are correctly read from the database and go through the writer?

Comment: i logged into the my h2 database console and run the query select * from family and the whole table shows up. that means the data is there. I posted my source code for my reader and writer. i do not know why the data is not written into xml file. could be from reader, writer or something else. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FileSystemResource` instead of `ClasspathResource` in the writer:

```
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("familyData.xml"));
```

Comment: I tried the FileSystemResource and it compiles fine, but still get the same result. the xml file still empty.